# How to access the error message using yup and react-hook-form through formState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to display the error message I set using yup validation - my schema for `displayName` looks like this:

```
 displayName: yup.string().required("Please enter a username")
```

I'm using react-hook-form for my forms and my textfield goes something like this:

```
    <Controller
      render={({ field, formState }) => (
      <TextField
      {...field}
      label="display name"
      error={!!formState.errors?.displayName}
      helperText={!!formState.errors?.displayName ? formState.errors?.displayName.message : null}
      />
     )}
     name="displayName"
     control={control}
     defaultValue=""
    />
```

Unfortunately, my screen goes blank. I tried looking for the reason why it happened and apparently, it's because of `formState.errors?.displayName.message` but at the same time, it contains the error message for my field. Is there any way I can access it so I can use it for my `helperText`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `TextField` a component of MUI?
I tried to reproduce it with `MUI + RHF + yup` in the same way,

> Is there any way I can access it so I can use it for my helperText?

It seems that the error is output to `helperText` without any problem.